# Check if a string contain characters with bad encoding

Tags: java, jackson

I receive a XML file with a tag whose value is "97ÃÂ²00430   ÃÂ²" while this tag initially contains only numbers. The encoding use is "ISO-8859-1".

How to detect the bad characters (ÃÂ²...) in java, please ?

LNA

Comment: I wonder if you could fix the problem at the source rather than detecting it afterwards? It smells strongly of a character encoding difference.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use a Regex to check the format of your tag (here, "\d+" if you want numbers only).

Answer (score -2):

```
public static String encode(String chr) {
  try {
   byte[] bytes = chr.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
   if (!validUTF8(bytes))
    return chr;   
   return new String(bytes, "UTF-8"); 
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

   throw new IllegalStateException("No char" + e.getMessage());
  }

 }
```

Comment: What is `validUTF8()`?

Comment: Its method where i put my logic to validate it.